# Watson Visual Recognition and Python

Tags: python, watson

I was trying to create a code using python that uses Watson Visual Recognition

I was wondering if you can send the image URL instead of a local image path to classify.

```
visual_recognition = VisualRecognitionV3(
version='2016-05-20',
api_key='###########################',
url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api')

classes = visual_recognition.classify(url='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4d/Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg/449px-Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg')        
print(json.dumps(classes, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using this.

```
visual_recognition = VisualRecognitionV3(
'2016-05-20',
api_key='#################')

classes = visual_recognition.classify(parameters = json.dumps({"url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4d/Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg/449px-Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg"}))
```